# How to prevent user change profile id in URL? Vue 3 Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, vue.js

I have a problem with vue 3 backend and nodejs mongodb. For example i have a user and admin role, admin role can access all menu in dashboard, but user only can edit their profile.

When i login as user and access edit profile menu, for example the url is localhost/profile/121 (121 is my user id), i will get my user data by id. But, user can edit the url id with another id, for example localhost/profile/122, and its not good.

How to prevent that user can only view or update their profile only? When at login page, i store the accesstoken, refreshtoken, id, and role in localStorage. And i see that localStorage can edited.

What is the best way for login in vue 3, nodejs with role model? And is that any way for prevent that user can only edit their data?

Thanks before.

Comment: When a request to a profile comes in, check that the incoming cookies or JWT or session ID or something corresponds properly to the profile being requested.

Comment: so, its better if i save role and id in accessToken?

Comment: Sure. Make sure that only the server can decode it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the id in the access token or the session.
Now every time a url is entered, see if the id is the same of the user, if yes, proceed. But, in case, it does not belong to the user, you can either redirect the user to the valid page or show `unauthorized` message.

Comment: is vue 3 have a session like php language?

Comment: I am not a vuejs person, but access tokens should surely work.